# Kendo UI grid version “v2012.3.1114” doesn't support Date/Time edit functionality

Tags: jquery, datetime, kendo-ui

I was previously using `Kendo-UI v2012.2.710` - but when I updated to `Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114` my code stopped working. I am not quite sure what changed, as my code seems pretty straight-forward. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Rolling back to the former version in order to keep this function working isn't an option, as it may break other functionality.

```
<div id="gridTiming"></div>

<script>
    var entries = [
        { "city":"Boston", "time":"10:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T10:14:00.000Z" },
        { "city":"Kyoto", "time":"23:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T23:14:00.000Z"},
        { "city":"La Paz", "time":"10:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T10:14:00.000Z"},
        { "city":"San Francisco", "time":"07:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T07:14:00.000Z"},
        { "city":"Salt Lake City", "time":"08:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T08:14:00.000Z"},
        { "city":"Salvador", "time":"11:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T11:14:00.000Z"},
        { "city":"Salzburg", "time":"16:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T16:14:00.000Z" },
        { "city":"San Diego", "time":"07:14", datetime: "2012-08-28T07:14:00.000Z" }
    ];

    function timeEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + 
                  options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + 
                  '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoTimePicker({});
    }

    function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
        console.log("options", options);
        $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + 
                  options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + 
                  '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDateTimePicker({});
    }

    $("#gridTiming").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: entries,
            schema: {
                parse: function (response) {
                    $.each(response, function (idx, elem) {
                        if (elem.time && typeof elem.time === "string") {
                            elem.time = kendo.parseDate(elem.time, "HH:mm");
                        }
                        if (elem.datetime && typeof elem.datetime === "string") {
                            elem.datetime = kendo.parseDate(elem.datetime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
                        }
                    });
                    return response;
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { command: [ "edit" ] },
            { field:"city", title:"City" },
            { field:"time", title:"Time", format:"{0:HH:mm}", editor: timeEditor },
            { field:"datetime", title:"Date - Time", format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", editor: dateTimeEditor }
        ],
        editable: "inline",
        navigatable: true
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT: The following pair of jsFiddles demonstrate the problem:**

- [Version 1, using `Kendo-UI v2012.2.710`](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vj2pE/3/)
- [Version 2, using `Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114`](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vj2pE/4/)

To see the issue, do the following:

1. Click "Edit" on a row
2. Change any items.
3. Click "Update"

[Troy Alford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454806/troy-alford): Both versions update the underlying grid's data - but only the `v2012.2.710` version closes the Dialog properly and marks the Grid's cells as having been changed.

Comment: I updated your question some to help you get more attention for it and make the code a little more readable.

Comment: What stopped working? Are there any javascript errors in the console? Give more info about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have created 2 jsFiddles for testing your issue <s>- but both versions of `Kendo-UI` work for me with no alteration to your code</s>.

- <s>[Version 1, using `Kendo-UI v2012.2.710`](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/vj2pE/1/)</s>
- <s>[Version 2, using `Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114`](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/vj2pE/2/)</s>

**EDIT:** Added the updated versions, provided by @Emiliano Bartolome to the OP. These links are:

- [Version 1, using `Kendo-UI v2012.2.710`](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vj2pE/3/)
- [Version 2, using `Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114`](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vj2pE/4/)

I should note that these jsFiddles rely on the `Kendo-UI` CDN and `jQuery 1.8.2` via CDN. The links I'm using are:

- `Kendo-UI v2012.2.710`: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js
- `Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114`: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.all.min.js
- `jQuery 1.8.2`: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: I have updated the code in your fiddles to actually show the "problem". If you press `edit` and the `update` in Kendo v2012.2.710 the `popup` window gets closed while in Kendo v2012.3.1114 it stays open. The fact is that in both the value gets updated but there is a different behavior. Is it a "bug" or "feature"?

Comment: Great - updating the OP's post with the fiddles, to elucidate.

Comment: Yes, @EmilianoBartolome I have same problem, Even I am not able to do any action on update funtion.

Comment: I have published the solution as a different answer. Check if it works for you and if so accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved! With the new version we have to have an `id` defined in the `schema.model`.

I've updated [Version 2, using Kendo-UI v2012.3.1114](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vj2pE/5/)

What I did in the model is set the `id` to the `city` and now it works!

```
model:{
    id:"city"
},
```

Comment: I have to restrict some records, for that I putted one condition 
edit: function (e) {
$('#gridTiming').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
},

But for the readonly records it's flickering.
Is there any other way to restrict records.